# Explicit wait in Selenium using C# with POM

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I am a beginner in test automation. The problem is that I want to click on a hamburger menu, then on 1st level navigation and after it on 2nd level navigation. But the problem is at 1st level navigation.

I found already out that I need to create an explicit wait before I can click on the 1st level navigation. But how can I do that on a way that it will work? I rried already a lot but without success.

Also let me know in which part I need to put the code.

Part of my code for the page:

```
     IWebDriver Driver;
        By Menu = By.Id("hamburger");

        //Tests for 1st navigation Collection
        By Collection = By.CssSelector("#list_681307 > li:nth-child(1) > span");

public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            Driver = driver;
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://....../");
        }
        public void HamburgerMenuClick()
        {
            Driver.FindElement(Menu).Click();
        }

        public bool HamburgerMenuPresent()
        {
            return Driver.FindElement(Menu).Displayed;
        }

 public void MenuClickCollection()
        {
            Driver.FindElement(Collection).Click();
        }
```

Part of my code for the test:

```
[TestFixture]
    class HomePageTests
    {
        IWebDriver Driver;
        HomePage Home;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            Driver = new ChromeDriver();
            Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Home = new HomePage(Driver);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            Driver.Quit();
        }

 [Test]
        public void MenuCollectionAll()
        {
            Home.HamburgerMenuClick();
            Home.MenuClickCollection();
            Home.MenuClickCollectionAll();
        }
```

This is the part of the HTML code

```
</div>
        <ul id="list_681307" class="navigation-list" data-level="1">
                <li class="item__level_1" data-title="Collection" data-level="1">
                    <span class="menu-link menu-button-link" data-image="0">Collection</span>
                    <button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="list_61596048" class="menu-link menu-button button--expand" data-image="0">Expand
                        <svg width="13px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 13 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="TOT-Icons-(✓-Eugene-2907)" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Icons" transform="translate(-255.000000, -34.000000)" fill="#231F20">
            <path d="M273,50.5515735 L271.661736,51.9587787 L261.5,41.5207883 L251.211621,52 L250,50.6020548 L259.520957,40.8242052 C260.590812,39.7252649 262.460224,39.7252649 263.530079,40.8242052 L273,50.5515735 Z" id="Fill-4" transform="translate(261.500000, 46.000000) rotate(-270.000000) translate(-261.500000, -46.000000) "></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg></button>
```

Now I think that maybe my CssSelector is not right.

Comment: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/advance-explicit-webdriver-waits-in-c/ this may help

Comment: Sorry I don't get it working.  And did check your link.

There must be a much easier way to write an explicited wait in c#.
So I have to wait till the MenuClickCollection is loaded on the website.

Comment: ` public void MenuClickCollection(){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement collection1 = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(Collection));
    collection1.Click();
 }`

Comment: Thank you Rahul L.

I have now:   public void MenuClickCollection()
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement collection1 = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(Collection));
            collection1.Click();
        }

And in test:
[Test]
        public void MenuCollectionAll()
        {
            Home.HamburgerMenuClick();
            Home.MenuClickCollection();
            Home.MenuClickCollectionAll();
}

Is that ok?

Comment: When I run the test I have now the following error:
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)

Help!

Comment: Added the part of the HTML code.

Comment: Are you able to click on By.Id("hamburger"); ? ElementNotInteractableException means element may be hidden or its not displayed yet.

Comment: Yes I am able to click on it.
It is working now but not with explicit wait.  When I use implicit wait it works :)

Comment: Now I need to change it into explicit wait.  Your code doesn't work for me sorry :(
Have now:  public void MenuClickCollection()
        {
            Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            Driver.FindElement(Collection).Click();
        }

And that works

Comment: Still not solved.  Can someone help me to get the explicit wait into my code?

I did test if it clicks the hamburger menu, and yes it does.
I also did test it with implicit wait and then it is working. But with explicit wait still getting an error.

Comment: Good news!  I solved it myself. Installed SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers

public void MenuClickCollection()
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(Collection));
            Driver.FindElement(Collection).Click();              
        }

Comment: @voetbalsuuske, of note, WaitHelpers is no longer maintained as a project. You may want to pull down the source into a project of your own to debug any issues with it that you nay come across.